# CakePHP CakeMail sending email to a TLS Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 (Hosted Exchange in Godaddy)

Tags: php, cakephp, exchange-server

I've been trying several configuration options to send email using CakePHP (CakeMail) to a Microsoft Exchange 2010 Server. This is my current configuration:

```
    public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('email@example.com' => 'Me'),
    'host' => 'smtp.ex3.secureserver.net',
    'port' => 587,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'verifiedUserName',
    'password' => 'verifiedPassword',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
    'delivery' => 'smtp'
);
```

And this is my testing function:

```
    public function test_email() {
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->config('default');
    debug($email->config());
    $result = $email->template('checkout')
            ->from('email@example.com')
            ->emailFormat('text')
            ->to('another@example.com')
            ->subject('TEST EMAIL ')
            ->send();
}
```

I'm getting a

```
SMTP Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

If i change the host to 'ssl://smtp.ex3.secureserver.net' or 'tls://smtp.ex3.secureserver.net' i'm getting a

```
Unable to connect to SMTP server.
```

The server is configured to use TLS.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(from the book)
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration

As of 2.3.0 you can also enable TLS SMTP using the tls option:

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => true
    );
}
```

ref to feature pull request here > https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/734

Answer (score 2):

You should use "tls"=>true in your $default config.